# converting word document from 2010 to 2016 version using ASPOSE API

Tags: .net, ms-word, aspose, word-2010

I just started using ASPOSE API for converting word document from 2010 to 2016 version.

Can anybody explain how can we convert word document from 2010 to 2016 version using ASPOSE API.

***Please give the code in detail.***

Till now I got to know that file extension of both 2010 and 2016 is same i.e. docx but the compatibility mode is different so if anyone help me out that how can we change the compatibility of word document using ASPOSE will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Document produced using the following code should cause no compatibility issues when opened in MS Word 2016:

```
Document doc = new Document(filePath);

OoxmlSaveOptions options = new OoxmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Docx);
options.Compliance = OoxmlCompliance.Iso29500_2008_Strict;

doc.Save("16.6.0.docx", options);
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Please note that this changes the conformance level of Open XML from transitional to strict. Something which might cause a lot of interop problems because the strict level is not supported by many tools (in fact, only Microsoft Word 2013 and later support it) -- so you should really know what you are doing when using the strict level.

Comment: We need to test this scenario on our end; and since you can't attach files in this forum, please post this requirement in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). Please zip and attach your 1) input, 2) Aspose.Words generated output and MS Word generated expected Word documents in your thread for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.